# A monad for piecewise mutable state

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I know how ordinary `State` works (**edit: apparently not!**).

If i need to create an array, and it is inconvenient to create the entire array at once, I can create an `STArray`, populate it, and then freeze and return a normal immutable array to the user.

Now suppose I need to create two arrays of different types simultaneously.

More generally, I may want to create an arbitrary graph with mutable nodes, modify it node by node for a while like I would modify an `STArray` cell by cell, and then freeze the whole graph at once and return normal immutable data.

I don't want to resort to `IOArray`s or anything in the `IO` monad. What are my options?

Comment: Why can you not just use `STArray`s?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Say I want to modify a cell in array1, calculated from  cells in array2. Then modify a cell in array2, calculated from  cells in array1. Repeat until done. Is this possible with just two STArrays? I don't see a way...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Hmm I guess it can be done with monad transformers. Stack the two states and lift as needed. Is this correct?

Comment: @n.m. Why monad transformers? Why not just put them both in ST? (Ok, I don't think it'd work with runSTArray because of the quantifiers, but I feel like there ought to be a way to do it - just use unsafeFreeze directly?)

Comment: @Cubic I somehow was under impression that you can only have one piece of state inside runST. Totally incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some options.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module TestSTArray where

import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array
import Data.Array.MArray

-- not needed until later on    
import GHC.Arr (unsafeFreezeSTArray)
```

The basic, safe way is to freeze. This will cause a copy, though.

```
test2Safe :: (Array Int Char, Array Int Bool)
test2Safe = runST $ do
   a1 <- newArray (0,9) 'A' :: ST s (STArray s Int Char)
   a2 <- newArray (0,9) False :: ST s (STArray s Int Bool)
   writeArray a1 5 'B'
   x <- readArray a2 6
   writeArray a1 7 (if x then 'X' else 'Y')
   writeArray a2 5 True
   arr1 <- freeze a1
   arr2 <- freeze a2
   return (arr1, arr2)
```

More risky, but probably still safe is to leverage lower lever / unsafe GHC primitives and build an extended variant of the safe `runSTArray`. In this way we avoid the copy.

```
runSTArray2 :: (forall s. ST s (STArray s i1 e1, STArray s i2 e2))
            -> (Array i1 e1, Array i2 e2) 
runSTArray2 st = runST $ do
  (a1, a2) <- st
  (,) <$> unsafeFreezeSTArray a1 <*> unsafeFreezeSTArray a2
```

I believe the above use of `unsafe` stuff is actually safe, since we no longer use `a1,a2` after the unsafe freeze, so no copy should be needed.

The above wrapper can be generalized to more arrays, of course. Arguably, a more general version should be put in the libraries.

Finally, we can exploit the auxiliary function:

```
test2LessSafe :: (Array Int Char, Array Int Bool)
test2LessSafe = runSTArray2 $ do
   a1 <- newArray (0,9) 'A' :: ST s (STArray s Int Char)
   a2 <- newArray (0,9) False :: ST s (STArray s Int Bool)
   writeArray a1 5 'B'
   x <- readArray a2 6
   writeArray a1 7 (if x then 'X' else 'Y')
   writeArray a2 5 True
   return (a1, a2)
```

Comment: Gosh, I feel so stupid now. Why didn't I see this. Thank you.